# Processing: Why is setup() running multiple times?

Tags: processing

I'm working on a visualisation app with Processing.

All appears to be going well, but I've noticed that in the console, I'm seeing any `println()` statements from the `setup()` method in triplicate. This doesn't appear to be the case for similar statements inside the `draw()` loop.

I thought this might just be an output thing, but I'm now seeing multiple attempts to open files. It will likely be taking its toll on performance, too.

Any idea how I can prevent this?

I'm using Processing 1.0.9 on Mac OS 10.6.3.

Thanks in advance,
Ross

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calls to `size()` and/or `hint()` cause `setup()` to be run again. Put those calls first to prevent other code (e.g. file loading) being affected.